# Can we use Realm database for free like alternative to Sqlite and CoreData?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, realm

I was doing a React-Native project. 
I was required to save data locally and then I decided to this in Realm.

Soon I found out it has pricing options for cloud database.
I'm not able to find out if this DB can use an alternative like sqlite or CoreData like it has mentioned:

```
"Used by 100k+ developers and downloaded over two billion times. Realm Database is a fast, easy to use, and open source alternative to SQLite and Core Data."
```

Can I use Realm for free for saving data locally?

Comment: Realm is free is you aren't using the cloud, it is a good option for a local database in your react-native app

Comment: @dentemm since they have clearly mentioned fast, easy to use, and open source alternative I agree with you, but I saw people in forum telling Realm is not free to use locally so I got confused .

Comment: @dentemm can you please confirm this ? meaning I wanted to know if you have used this or by any way you weren't forced to pay after 30 days .

Comment: @user3804063 No they are not asking for pay for sure. I am using realm since 2 years.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes definitely you can use `Realm` for free to save unlimited data locally. `Realm` is only charging for `cloud storage`.

[Realm Cloud Storage Pricing](https://realm.io/pricing)

Comment: I was looking from someone who is using Realm . Thank you man thanks a lot .

Comment: with your words I'm going to use Realm in my current project .

Comment: Since last 2 years I am using Realm for my each and every project. So I am confident about it.

Comment: Not yet but one of my friend is using cloud service. So as per his review it's also a good option for cloud storage as well. As they are providing fast support.

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya Well, not exactly. If you want to use features like device synchronization and want to go for a Self Hosted Realm Object Server, you have to pay for that. The realm site is tricky, they make you think that only their cloud service is a paid one, but it is not true.

Answer (score 11):

I spent considerable amount of time and found out :

Self hosted “realm platform/ros” - **not free starting 3.5.0**

- “Starting with Realm Object Server 3.5.0, a feature token is required
  to run the server. You can get your own feature token [here](https://realm.io/trial/self-hosted-standard-plan/).”
- Above is the same as the [pricing page](https://realm.io/pricing)
- Standard is $30/month and Dedicated Cloud for custom pricing

“Realm platform/ros” - **not open source**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/realm-object-server points to https://github.com/realm/ros which gives 404, implies private repo
- https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server is open source, but it is just tracking of issues related to the Realm Object Server and other general issues not related to the specific SDK's

“Realm platform/ros” - **data integration needs license/unmaintained/create data connector/create APIs**

- “The Realm Platform allows for [easy integration](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/backend-integration) with your existing backend whether that is databases, microservices, APIs, etc. There are three common ways to do this:”
- - [MSSQL Data Connector](https://docs.realm.io/sync/backend-integration/mssql-data-connector) (MSSQL needs license/paid)
- - [Postgres Connector](https://docs.realm.io/sync/backend-integration/postgres-connector) (Distribution of the Postgres data connector package is currently paused. This page is only available for reference. We apologize for the inconvenience.)
- - [Own data connector](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/backend-integration#writing-your-own-data-connector-using-the-adapter-api) (we do not currently support out of the box (i.e. MongoDB, MySQL, etc))
- - [Server SDK](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/backend-integration#server-sdks) + [data change event handlers in server SDK](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/backend-integration#event-handler) (Javascript and .NET) + [via GraphQL](https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/backend-integration#graphql) (available via GraphQL endpoints for users whose backend is not natively supported by our SDKs (i.e. Java, Python, etc))

“Realm platform/ros and cloud” - **data querying/exporting**

- Uses [GraphQL to browse data](https://docs.realm.io/sync/backend-integration/data-integration) in realm cloud instances and “Realm platform/ros and the same can be used for data export/data pipeline jobs to send data to analytics platform

Hope this saves time for other readers !

Answer (score 4):

I currently use realm in a production application with exactly this use case.
Pros: Fast read and writes good documentation.
Cons: Models get messy
Clogs up JS thread
Impossible to debug
Realm objects make tranlating to the redux store a major pain

My advice is use watermelonDb

Comment: `make tranlating to the redux store a major pain` this is actually a downside coming from the Naiveness of Redux as an "architecture pattern", and not a problem of Realm itself.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't disagree with you at all. However, redux seems to come with react now as the "Give developers something they are familiar with" argument always gets made. Believe me, if I had my choice I would have scrapped redux all together and used the Realm.observable.